# Changing a Field Based on Another Field

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a form where you have a dropdown box where you can change the aircraft type, but I would like to have another field called "Registrations", which changes the available registrations of the aircraft automatically based on the selected aircraft.

Here's the code:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>Aircraft:</td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="type" id="Aircraft" value="<?php echo "{$schedule->aircraft}"; ?>">
        <?php
        $equipment = OperationsData::getAllAircraftSingle(true);
        if(!$equipment) $equipment = array();
        foreach($equipment as $equip)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$equip->icao.'">'.$equip->icao.' - '.$equip->name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Registration:</td>
        <td><input class="form-control" name="reg" id="Aircraft Registration" size="5" type="text" placeholder="YU-" maxlength="4" readonly value="<?php echo "{$schedule->registration}"; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
```

PHP codes should not be modified, as they echo the aircraft and registrations to these fields.

Comment: Javascript is the way to modify your page at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution using jquery(javascript lib)

```
 $('select#Aircraft').change(function(){
     //you can grab selected option here with
    var value = $('select#Aircraft:selected').text();
    //now you can grab the registration input field and to something about it
    // as now am adding the text grabbed from selected option
    $('#Registration').val(value);
  })
```